# OCSP invalidation of intermediate CA using OCSP_SIGNING

Tags: openssl, x.509, ocsp

I'm implementing an OCSP server to answer OCSP requests for my custom CA.

I already implemented the invalidation of leaves certificates, with the intermediate CA certificate signing the OCSP response, and it seems to be working.

However, I have troubles implementing the OCSP response to invalidate a intermediate certificate. I believe this is a bad idea to use the root certificate to sign the OCSP response, therefore I was looking at the OCSP delegation of authority defined in [RFC 6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#section-2.6). I have generated, using my root certificate, a certificate which I believe to be able to sign OCSP responses for OCSP requests about the other intermediate certificates :

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    ... //redacted
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            CRL Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE

        OCSP No Check: critical

        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            OCSP Signing
```

Let's call this certificate X

However, when I challenge my OCSP server with a request, openssl gives me the following answer :

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer /tmp/ca-root -cert /tmp/inter -text -url http://127.0.0.1:5000/1/ocsp-inter/
...
Response Verify Failure
139690508489984:error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found:crypto/ocsp/ocsp_vfy.c:40:
139690508489984:error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found:crypto/ocsp/ocsp_vfy.c:40:
/tmp/inter: ERROR: No Status found.
```

What am I missing ?
If I select the certificate X for the `-issuer` switch of openSSL it works, but it feels wrong.

I also had a look at the AIA extensions, and I'm unsure if the CA_ISSUER field should point to the root-ca, or to my certificate X

Thanks in advance helping me understand this

Comment: Unfortunately that error is pretty common. Could be multiple things but the most likely is a problem with the responder. Can you test the responder using known good certificates?

Comment: The certificate I used in this example is indeed a known good :( That's the main issue, I don't know if the fact that I have to indicate that the issuer is not the _real_ issuer but the certificate that will be used to sign the OCSP response in order to get a "Response Verifiy Success" is wrong or not. I believe it is wrong, it feels wrong, but I can't put the pin on what's the good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have some experience in implementing an OCSP responder.

You might see "signer certificate not found" error if you didn't add the OCSP signing certificate, X, into the BasicOCSPResponse.

```
BasicOCSPResponse ::= SEQUENCE {
  tbsResponseData          ResponseData,
  signatureAlgorithm       AlgorithmIdentifier,
  signature                BIT STRING,
  certs                [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE OF Certificate OPTIONAL }
```